# Serial connection of many elements in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need to connect 99 blocks serial. Can I do it not manually? For example define type of connection (serial\ parallel) and number of blocks forming this connection?

Answer (score 2):

[`add_line`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_line.html) is an api function which allows you to add the lines. Other relevant functions you probably need are `find_system` and `add_block`